# DrawText draws Segoe UI font texts incorrectly

Tags: winapi, vb6, ocx, drawtext

I encountered one problem with drawing texts using the Windows API DrawText call for the Segoe UI font:

[image]

This image demonstrates the problem: the specified text is shifted a little bit to the right in the specified rectangle so the last character is clipped (the best example is the 0 digit).

Our drawing routine works well for other fonts, and the problem occurs only for Segoe UI.

What it could be and how to solve it?

Doing this in a VB6 OCX project on Windows 8 Pro 64-bit if it matters.

---

The corresponding code source snippet is the following:

```
' Only draws or measure text (if DT_CALCRECT is specified)
' using the native WinAPI flags:
Public Sub gpInternalDrawText( _
     ByVal lHDC As Long, _
     ByRef sText As String, _
     ByRef tR As RECT, _
     ByVal lFlags As Long _
  )
  ' Allows Unicode rendering of text under NT/2000/XP
  If (g_bIsNt) Then
     ' NT4 crashes with ptr = 0
     If StrPtr(sText) <> 0 Then
        DrawTextW lHDC, StrPtr(sText), -1, tR, lFlags
     End If
  Else
     DrawTextA lHDC, sText, -1, tR, lFlags
  End If
End Sub

' Draws the string in the specifed rectangle.
' Should not be called to calculate text size
' (with DT_CALCRECT flag - use gpInternalDrawText instead)
Public Sub DrawText( _
     ByVal lHDC As Long, _
     ByRef sText As String, _
     ByRef rcText As RECT, _
     ByVal lFlags As Long, _
     Optional ByVal eAlignH As Long = 0, _
     Optional ByVal eAlignV As Long = 0 _
  )

  ' *** Automatically turns processing prefixes off (if required)

  If (lFlags And &H200000) = 0 Then
     lFlags = lFlags Or DT_NOPREFIX
  Else
     lFlags = lFlags Xor DT_PREFIXONLY
  End If


  ' *** We can modify rcText below, so do it with its copy

  Dim rcDrawText As RECT
  LSet rcDrawText = rcText


  ' *** Getting the full set of API flags for our text

  Select Case eAlignH
  ' in fact don't need that as DT_LEFT=0:
'   Case igAlignHLeft
'      lFlags = lFlags Or DT_LEFT
  Case igAlignHCenter
     lFlags = lFlags Or DT_CENTER
  Case igAlignHRight
     lFlags = lFlags Or DT_RIGHT
  End Select

  If (lFlags And DT_SINGLELINE) <> 0 Then
     Select Case eAlignV
     ' in fact don't need that as DT_TOP=0:
  '   Case igAlignVTop
  '      lFlags = lFlags Or DT_TOP
     Case igAlignVCenter
        lFlags = lFlags Or DT_VCENTER
     Case igAlignVBottom
        lFlags = lFlags Or DT_BOTTOM
     End Select
  Else
     If eAlignV <> igAlignVTop Then
        Dim rcCalcRect As RECT
        LSet rcCalcRect = rcText
        gpInternalDrawText lHDC, sText, rcCalcRect, lFlags Or DT_CALCRECT
        Dim lTextHeight As Long
        lTextHeight = rcCalcRect.Bottom - rcCalcRect.Top
        Select Case eAlignV
        Case igAlignVCenter
           ' simplified (rcText.Top + rcText.Bottom) / 2 - lTextHeight / 2
           ' should be integer division because of rounding erros in the case of "/"
           rcDrawText.Top = (rcDrawText.Top + rcDrawText.Bottom - lTextHeight) \ 2
        Case igAlignVBottom
           rcDrawText.Top = rcDrawText.Bottom - lTextHeight
        End Select
     End If
  End If


  ' *** Finally draw the text

  Const FIXED_PATH_ELLIPSIS_FLAGS As Long = DT_SINGLELINE Or DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS
  If (lFlags And FIXED_PATH_ELLIPSIS_FLAGS) = FIXED_PATH_ELLIPSIS_FLAGS Then
     DrawText_FixedPathEllipsis lHDC, sText, rcDrawText, lFlags
  Else
     gpInternalDrawText lHDC, sText, rcDrawText, lFlags
  End If

End Sub
```

The font for the UserControl DC is set using this code:

```
Public Function FontHandle(fnt As IFont) As Long
   FontHandle = fnt.hFont
End Function

Private Sub pApplyFont()
   If (m_hFntDC <> 0) Then
      If (m_hDC <> 0) Then
         If (m_hFntOldDC <> 0) Then
            SelectObject m_hDC, m_hFntOldDC
         End If
      End If
   End If

   m_hFntDC = FontHandle(UserControl.Font)
   If (m_hDC <> 0) Then
      m_hFntOldDC = SelectObject(m_hDC, m_hFntDC)
   End If
End Sub
```

, where

```
m_hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(UserControl.hdc)
```

Comment: We cannot see any code. We've no idea therefore what you did. Please show the code.

Comment: There's nothing there relating to the font. Where do you create the font and select it into the DC? I can guess what is going on but it would be better if we say it plainly.

Comment: Quote: "Segoe UI is optimized for ClearType, which is on by default in Windows. With ClearType enabled, Segoe UI is an elegant, readable font. Without ClearType enabled, Segoe UI is only marginally acceptable. This factor determines when you should use Segoe UI".  You found out what "marginally acceptable" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the output quality that you are using. You are using `ANTIALIASED_QUALITY`. Segoe UI has been designed for clear type. It looks great with clear type, but terrible with standard anti-aliasing. Switch to clear type (set `lqQuality` to `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY`) and you will get much better results.

This image demonstrates rendering of 10pt Segoe UI with the two quality options discussed above.

[image]

Comment: I do not create the API font object - I borrow the existing Font object from the UserControl (an StdFont type). I've added more code to the question to demonstrate this. Can I set the required font quality for the existing API font, or do that for the DC?

Comment: Well, now we are into VB6 user controls which is not my bag. I'm pretty sure that the issue is exactly what I said. I wonder why you aren't picking up clear type. Do you have it disabled on your machine? I would have expected the VB6 framework to have used `DEFAULT_QUALITY` which will give you the system quality. Which is clear type by default. I think you first of all need to work out why you are not rendering using clear type. I don't think that I can answer that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, David Heffernan was right - I needed to turn the ClearType setting for the whole OS on:

[image]

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @apomene: actually, it is a form of an answer. The issue has been solved by "turning on the ClearType setting in the OS settings".

Comment: @apomene,@quetzalcoatl: yes, it was a form to publish an answer to my question as I did not find another better way.